# Accessing information from another viewController

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I am new to swift and I am trying to repopulate a pickerview using an array of names from another class. I have this class Notes that creates notes and each note has a name/title, I am trying to access those names/title and put them in pickerview, can anyone help me.

```
import UIKit
var allNotes: [Note] = []
var currentNoteindex: Int = -1
var noteTable: UITableView?
let kAllNotes:String = "notes"

class Note: NSObject
{
    var date:String
    var note:String
    var name:String

    override init()
    {
        date = NSDate().description
        name = ""
        note = ""
    }

    func dictionary() -> NSDictionary
    {
        return ["note": note, "date": date, "name": name]
    }
```

I have two different pickerview and one works it's just the one with the names doesn't work.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fileNamePicker.dataSource = self
    fileNamePicker.delegate = self

    gradePicker.dataSource = self
    gradePicker.delegate = self

}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    if pickerView == gradePicker
    {
        return grades.count
    }
    else
    {
        return allNotes.count
    }

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    if pickerView == gradePicker
    {
       return grades[row]
    }

    else
    {
         //This is where the Problem is, but I don't know how to fix it.
        let nameFiles = allNotes[currentNoteindex].name 
        return nameFiles[row]
    }

}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}
```

Comment: `let nameFiles = allNotes[currentNoteindex].name` is already a `String`. Why don't you just return the var?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but it doesn't work too.

Comment: What do you mean `doesn't work`?  Can you add more detail here?

Comment: like I did                                                                                                       
 var nameFiles = allNotes[currentNoteindex].name 
        return nameFiles                                                                                
 and it didn't display the names at all.

Comment: I'm saying `return nameFiles` because it is already a string.

Comment: It's what I did but still doesn't display the names.

Comment: Is there any object in `allNotes` array? What is the result of `allNotes.count`?

Comment: it looks like a bunch of zeros

Comment: You found the reason. Nothing in the array, so nothing to show.

Comment: so how do I create the object? I new at swift I really don't know the syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nameFiles` is accessing a name from a note.

`nameFiles[row]` doesn't work because `nameFiles` is not an array.

If you want to return a string, simply do `return nameFiles`. Check first to make sure that `nameFiles` actually has a value, though!

Comment: Check where you are setting the name variable for the note class.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your allNotes array is empty. You have initilaize but does not seems to append the object. Create `initiliaze` method inside `Note` class

```
init(_ date: String, note: String, name: String) {
        self.date = date
        self.note = note
        self.name = name
    }
```

In your viewcontroller class try appending like this. Now below you can access inside picker view method:-

```
//You can append by doinf iteration based on your data
allNotes.append(Note(date: "value1", note: "Value", name: "name"))
```